# Renaming lucene-core jar fails elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

We have changed lucene-core and using (added this custom jar in elasticsearch core build.gradle) it in our elasticsearch.

We are able to create distribution using:

```
gradle assemble
```

and in libs we can see our custom lucene-core jar. But when we run elastic search using bin/elasticsearch it gives following error:

```
[2017-03-06T13:31:45,311][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [3OVrb59] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-03-06T13:31:45,312][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [3OVrb59] no plugins loaded
[2017-03-06T13:31:45,813][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] fatal error in thread [main], exiting
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.StemmerOverrideFilter$Builder.build(StemmerOverrideFilter.java:205) ~[lucene-analyzers-common-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:51]
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.nl.DutchAnalyzer.<init>(DutchAnalyzer.java:133) ~[lucene-analyzers-common-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:51]
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.nl.DutchAnalyzer.<init>(DutchAnalyzer.java:106) ~[lucene-analyzers-common-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:51]
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.PreBuiltAnalyzers$20.create(PreBuiltAnalyzers.java:246) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.PreBuiltAnalyzers.getAnalyzer(PreBuiltAnalyzers.java:487) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry$PrebuiltAnalysis.<init>(AnalysisRegistry.java:335) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry$PrebuiltAnalysis.<init>(AnalysisRegistry.java:320) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry.<init>(AnalysisRegistry.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.analysis.AnalysisModule.<init>(AnalysisModule.java:175) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:307) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:220) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:192) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:192) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:287) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.nfdb.NFDB.main(NFDB.java:15) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessDeclaredMembers")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2348) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1915) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator$1.run(RamUsageEstimator.java:339) ~[lucene-core-custom.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator$1.run(RamUsageEstimator.java:1) ~[lucene-core-custom.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator.shallowSizeOfInstance(RamUsageEstimator.java:336) ~[lucene-core-custom.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.RamUsageEstimator.shallowSizeOf(RamUsageEstimator.java:313) ~[lucene-core-custom.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.ByteSequenceOutputs.<clinit>(ByteSequenceOutputs.java:154) ~[lucene-core-custom.jar:6.2.1 43ab70147eb494324a1410f7a9f16a896a59bc6f - shalin - 2016-09-15 05:15:20]
    ... 21 more
```

Renaming the jar file back to the old name i.e. lucene-core-6.2.1 in the lib folder fixes the problem.

I was trying to debug the issue but couldn't find the root cause. 
In PrebuiltAnalyzer commenting the DUTCH enum fixes the issue.

We re using elasticsearch 5.0.1 and lucene-6.2.1 (customized)

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry...updated above...